# Is there a known theory regarding decomposing trivariate functions into composition of two bivariate functions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, functional-equations

I would like to take a given trivariate function $f(x,y,z)$ and decompose it into two bivariate functions $g$ and $h$ like so:

$$f(x,y,z) = g(x, h(y,z))$$

Is there a known theory regarding when this is possible, given certain conditions, for example, all values are real, and $f$ is a polynomial (or rational, or analytic etc.) function, and g and h are (polynomial, rational, analytic etc.) I am especially interested in the case where $f$ is symmetric in $y$ and $z$. That is, $f(x,y_0,z_0) = f(x, z_0, y_0)$

I can randomly perform such decompositions by trial and error, but I am seeking a methodical understanding.

Comment: I think the "known theory" is called "mathematics". $$f(x,y,z) = g(x, h(y,z))$$ is trivial, if $g=f$ and $h(y,z)=(y,z)$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That seems unnecessarily harsh. The OP says "all values are real", which presumably means $h$ should be a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. Of course, one can encode a pair of real numbers as a single real number, but since there is no continuous injective function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, such a "coding" function will fail any of the regularity properties the OP is interested in (being a polynomial, rational, analytic, etc.).

Comment: @Alex Kruckman The OP did no such thing. If you feel like that, you may investigate the regularity properties of "etc" (explicitely included in the domain). Have fun! And no, that's not harsh. This is a site allegedly devoted to mathematics, that would ask for some minimum of rigour.

Comment: Sorry, when you say "the OP did not such thing", what "such thing" are you referring to? Note that this question is closely related to Hilbert's 13th problem, and many mathematicians have had fun working on this topic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for the pointer to Hilbert's 13th problem. I looked at the Wikipedia page and it does directly relate to my question. I guess the answer is that there are some known results, for example with continuous functions, but the question is still open for other classes of functions, such as  algebraic functions. (BTW, I was aware of Prof Vector's solution of using tuples. But it is trivial, and doesn't answer other variants of the question, such as when g and h are required to be polynomial functions.)

Comment: Note that the representation you're asking for ($f(x,y,z) = g(x,h(y,z))$) is different from  the representation obtained by Arnold and Kolmogorov for multivariate continuous functions. See the beautiful answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/322185/2126) for a continuous function of three variables that cannot be represented in this form. @ProfessorVector

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Thank you, especially for the link. It is disappointing that such a simple function fails to be decomposable into functions in that way with such a weak constraint as continuity.  C'est la vie.

Comment: "Sorry, when you say "the OP did not such thing", what "such thing" are you referring to? " Sorry, what are *you* referring to?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sigh, ok. I said "The OP says "all values are real"". You said "The OP did no such thing". That confused me, because "all values are real" is a direct quote from the question, so I asked you to clarify. But this is clearly not a productive conversation, so let's end it here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the domain of all the variables is the same (e.g. all of them are reals), in theory this is always possible if this domain is infinite. This is because for any infinite set $X$, there always exists a bijection from $X \to X \times X$. Let $h$ be such a bijection, and define
$$g(x, k) = f(x, h^{-1}(k))$$
We have in essence taken $y, z \in X$ and "condensed" them into one value $k \in X$, without losing any information.

With a similar counting argument, you can reason that it cannot always be possible if the domain is finite. If $f$ can be decomposed as $g(x, h(y, z))$, with $g: X^2 \to X$ and $h: X^2 \to X$, then we will know that $f$ can only take at maximum $|X|^2$ distinct values.

A couple remarks:

1. Unfortunately, this bijection won't always be nice (e.g. there does not exist a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$). Thus, your hopes of making $g$ and $h$ polynomials will require $f$ to have further qualifications. No sufficient criterion for $f$ come to mind at the moment for me, though.
2. You can use this same argument to reason about the case where the domains/ranges are not all the same set, e.g. $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$.